# How do I only transition objects greater than 100MB to AWS Glacier from S3 Standard using AWS Lifecycle Management Policies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier, s3-lifecycle-policy

I have 50TB of data in an S3 Standard bucket.

I want to transition objects that are greater than 100MB & older than 30 days to AWS Glacier using an S3 Lifecycle Policy.

**How can I only transition objects that are greater than 100MB in size?**

Answer (score 2):

**There is no way to transition items based on file size.**

As the name suggests, S3 *Lifecycle* policies allow you to specify transition actions based on object *lifetime* - not file size - to move items from the S3 Standard storage class to S3 Glacier.

Now, a really inefficient & costly way that may be suggested would be to schedule a Lambda to check the S3 bucket daily, see if anything is 30 days old & then "move" items to Glacier.

However, **the Glacier API does not allow you to *move* items from S3 Standard to Glacier unless it is through a lifecycle policy**.

This means you will need to *download* the S3 object and then *re-upload* the item again to Glacier.

I would still advise having a Lambda running daily to check the file size of items, however, create another folder (key) called *archive* for example. If there are any items older than 30 days & greater than 100MB, [copy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CopyObject.html) the item from the current folder to the *archive* folder and then delete the original item.

**Set a 0-day life-cycle policy, filtered on the prefix of the other folder (*archive*), which then transitions the items to Glacier ASAP.**

This way, you will be able to transfer items larger than 100MB after 30 days, without paying higher per-request charges associated with uploading items to Glacier, which may even cost you more than the savings you were aiming for in the first place.

To later transition the object(s) back from Glacier to S3 Standard, use the [`RestoreObject`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_RestoreObject.html) API (or SDK equivalent) to restore it back into the original folder. Then finally, delete the object from Glacier using a [`DELETE` request to the archive URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/api-archive-delete.html).

Answer (score 1):

In the "Lifecycle rule configuration" there is (from Nov 23, 2021 - see References 1.) a "Object size" form field on which you can specify both the minimum and the maximum object size.

[image]

For the sake of completeness, by default Amazon S3 does not transition objects that are smaller than 128 KB for the following transitions:

- From the S3 Standard or S3 Standard-IA storage classes to S3 Intelligent-Tiering or S3 Glacier Instant Retrieval.
- From the S3 Standard storage class to S3 Standard-IA or S3 One Zone-IA

References:

1. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/11/amazon-s3-lifecycle-storage-cost-savings/
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-transition-general-considerations.html

Answer (score 0):

create a [lambda that runs every day](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) (cron job) that checks for files older than 30 days and greater then 100mb in the bucket. You can use the [s3 api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Type_API_Reference.html) and  [glacier api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/amazon-glacier-api.html).